# i just have Downloaded spectacle and the app icon shows as gear is this a malicious app or this is just a problem?

Tags: 22.04, security, malware

I just Downloaded spectacle `sudo apt-get install spectacle` and the app icon shows as gear. Is this a malicious app or this is just a problem?

Comment: In most cases a gear icon means that the real icon has failed to load. That can be due to various reasons, but usually because something is misconfigured. In most cases it isn't a security risk, but if you're concerned, you could try with the [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/spectacle) for spectacle instead of the apt one.

Comment: The `spectacle` package was removed from the Ubuntu (deb) repositories after 18.04. It is no longer available for any supported release of Ubuntu. This suggests that you may be running an old release that we no longer provide support for. If so, you may have a bigger problem than the gear icon.

Comment: @user535733 Spectacle still is available as a snap, so there is a chance OP has it installed as a snap. I can reproduce that installing Spectacle as a Snap result

Comment: @vanadium agreed, I wondered about that possibility, teetered on the edge about assuming if `apt-get` was accurate. Hence comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Software that you obtain using Ubuntu Software in principle has been checked by the Ubuntu developpers. That means that there is little chance that malware would make it through. If it ever makes it into Ubuntu Software, it would likely be reported rather quickly and fixed. So it is not expected that you are dealing with malicious software.

Still, there might be packaging issues with software. That a generic icon is shown rather than a specific icon is likely due to issues with how the software is packaged. It is the responsibility of the packager to also correctly set up an icon.

On a final note, you did not specify the desktop environment you use. Spectacle is a screenshot application intended for the Plasma desktop. A default Ubuntu install, however, uses the Gnome Shell desktop environment. Spectacle will not work on a default Ubuntu desktop that runs on Wayland.

So if you are on a standard Ubuntu install, but want an alternative screenshot utility, select one that is intended to work with the Gnome Shell desktop or another desktop that is based on the GTK toolkit.